# Upgrade of Mongodb Driver to 4.7.0 is not working in spring boot 2.7.15

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data-mongodb

I am trying to upgrade the MongoDB driver to 4.7.0 from 4.6.1 but the driver is not getting upgrade to MongoDb driver 4.7.0. Have tried with springboot 2.7.15 version but the driver is not getting upgrade to MongoDB driver 4.7.0. Maven pom.xml looks like below. I want to use inbuilt version of mongodb driver 4.7.0 but the version upgrade is not happening. Can anyone help me how to upgrade the mongoDB driver 4.7.0. Appreciate any help.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.agcs.cids</groupId>
    <artifactId>SampleService</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <packaging>jar</packaging>

    <name>SampleService</name>
    <description>Project for SampleService Service</description>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <springboot.version>2.7.15</springboot.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.8</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.8</maven.compiler.target>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <surefire-plugin.version>2.22.0</surefire-plugin.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-validation</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.8.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>



    </dependencies>

    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>spring-milestone</id>
            <name>Spring Maven MILESTONE Repository</name>
            <url>https://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.22.2</version>
                <configuration>
                    <systemProperties>
                        <java.util.logging.manager>org.jboss.logmanager.LogManager</java.util.logging.manager>
                    </systemProperties>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <configuration>
                    <arguments>
                        <source>1.8</source>
                        <target>1.8</target>
                        <uberJar>true</uberJar>
                    </arguments>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>toolchain-nexus</id>
            <url>${nexus.release.url}</url>
        </repository>

        <snapshotRepository>
            <id>toolchain-nexus</id>
            <url>${nexus.snapshot.url}</url>
        </snapshotRepository>
    </distributionManagement>
</project>
```

Comment: `spring-boot-starter-parent` should be used as parent of your POM, if you want to import a BOM you should use `spring-boot-dependencies`, see https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#using.parent-pom

Comment: @Pino , Thank you for the immediate response .I am using as like below dependency and mentioned in properties as like . And below configuration worked while upgrading the mongoDB driver to 4.6.1    version <springboot.version>2.7.15</springboot.version>
        <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
                <version>${springboot.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the dependency for the specific version of the driver you wish to use.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
    <artifactId>mongodb-driver-sync</artifactId>
    <version>4.7.0</version>
</dependency>
```

Maven will honor this version instead of the transient version supplied with Spring.

By the way, it appears SpringData MongoDB version 2.7.15 has mongodb driver sync 4.6.1 as it's transient dependency, not 4.7.0

It looks like SpringData MongoDB 3.0.10 has a transient dependency on mongodb driver sync version 4.8.2